# How to safely shutdown the entire hbase cluster?

Tags: hbase

The official doc shows in detail how to config and start the hbase cluster, but says little about a shutdown.

I have two tactics to stop the entire cluster:

1. stop all the region server first and then stop the master, by script 'hbase-daemon.sh'
2. stop master first and then stop all the region server, also by script 'hbase-daemon.sh'

I have tried the first sequence, stop all the region server first and then stop the master. But this could cause a problem: when you close some of all the region server, master would perceive and move the regions of the closed region servers to the rest of the region servers, but the rest of the region servers may not have sufficient memory so that they would crash, rather than exit normally.

The second sequence looks safer than the first, but I haven't given it a try.

Can someone help clarify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a script stop-hbase.sh in the /bin directory which seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Could you please tell me how dose the script stop-hbase.sh work? I read the script and found it just send a rpc request to the master. What will happen next?  Will the master shutdown all the region servers by rpc before shutdown itself?

Comment: I don't know the exact order in which master/zookeeper/region servers get shut down, but it seems to be done gracefully. It seems to rely on SSH to communicate with each respective region server. Once you issue this command, all HBase related daemons are shut down on all region server machines, which you can check via the jps command on each region server and the master.